# Package requirements 'tensorflow~=2.10.0', 'transformers~=4.22.1', 'TorchCRF~=1.1.0' are not satisfied

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, pycharm, huggingface-transformers

I am using PyCharm 2022.2.3 (Professional Edition), Python 3.11.0 (have any problem in compatible between this version of Python with PyTorch?) , Windows 11 x64.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.674]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\donhu>python
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 24 2022, 18:26:48) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

File `requirement.txt`

```py
tensorflow~=2.10.0
numpy~=1.23.3
# torch==1.12.1
PyYAML~=6.0
pandas~=1.5.0
transformers~=4.22.1
TorchCRF~=1.1.0
tqdm~=4.64.1
seqeval~=1.2.2
viet-text-tools==0.1.1
```

Error

```
Package requirements 'tensorflow~=2.10.0', 'transformers~=4.22.1', 'TorchCRF~=1.1.0' are not satisfied
```

File `train.py`

```py
import argparse
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import torch
from TorchCRF import CRF
import transformers
from data import Dataset
from engines import train_fn
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--data_file", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--hyps_file", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
data_file = yaml.load(open(args.data_file), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
hyps_file = yaml.load(open(args.hyps_file), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    Dataset(
        df=pd.read_csv(data_file["train_df_path"]),
        tag_names=data_file["tag_names"],
        tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"], use_fast=False),
    ),
    num_workers=hyps_file["num_workers"],
    batch_size=hyps_file["batch_size"],
    shuffle=True,
)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    Dataset(
        df=pd.read_csv(data_file["val_df_path"]),
        tag_names=data_file["tag_names"],
        tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"], use_fast=False),
    ),
    num_workers=hyps_file["num_workers"],
    batch_size=hyps_file["batch_size"] * 2,
)
loaders = {
    "train": train_loader,
    "val": val_loader,
}
model = transformers.RobertaForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(hyps_file["encoder"],
                                                                   num_labels=data_file["num_tags"])
if hyps_file["use_crf"]:
    criterion = CRF(num_tags=data_file["num_tags"], batch_first=True)
else:
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=float(hyps_file["lr"]))
train_fn(
    loaders, model, torch.device(hyps_file["device"]), hyps_file["device_ids"],
    criterion,
    optimizer,
    epochs=hyps_file["epochs"],
    ckp_path="../ckps/{}.pt".format(hyps_file["encoder"].split("/")[-1]),
)
```

Message

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the
```

Even update pip, not resolve problem

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Click on the `Install requirements` =)

Comment: In the end the problem is that Python 3.11 is too new and a lot of software has not been packaged for it yet.

Answer (score 2):

For PyCharm, take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html#populate_dependency_files

After you've set it up, you can click `Install requirement`.

> Open a project with the requirements file specified, a notification bar is displayed on top of any Python or requirements file opened in Editor:

[image]

---

Beyond PyCharm you should also learn some bits of conda and different Python environment setup: https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

---

First read this https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ and https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html, then most probably, try conda before attempting the following.

And if you're still having issues after trying the above, then it's time to consider manually updating the (possibly stale) `requirements.txt`, e.g.

[image]

With the requirements:

```
tensorflow~=2.10.0
numpy~=1.23.3
# torch==1.12.1
PyYAML~=6.0
pandas~=1.5.0
transformers~=4.22.1
TorchCRF~=1.1.0
tqdm~=4.64.1
seqeval~=1.2.2
viet-text-tools==0.1.1
```

We must first kind of determine which one is lowest in the food chain that requires the most dependencies.

**Generic Python libraries**

```
tqdm~=4.64.1
PyYAML~=6.0
```

**Data related:**

```
pandas~=1.5.0
numpy~=1.23.3
```

**Popular Machine Learning related:**

```
tensorflow~=2.10.0
# torch==1.12.1
transformers~=4.22.1
```

**Less popular machine learning tools:**

```
seqeval~=1.2.2
TorchCRF~=1.1.0
viet-text-tools==0.1.1
```

- For the **generic python tools**, it should be very safe to just **update them to the LATEST version possible**
- For the **data related and machine learning tools**, the library that has the most dependencies would most probably be the `transformers`. In that case, **you can safely update `transformers` to the LATEST STABLE version** and that should give you appropriate matching numpy, pandas, tensorflow and pytorch versions.

Up till now our new `requirements.txt` would look like this:

```
tqdm
PyYAML
transformers
```

- Now, looking at the [seqeval](https://pypi.org/project/seqeval/), it's a library that most probably work well with transformers, so adding it without specifying version should be okay
- Then we have the `viet-text-tools==0.1.1` tagged to a specific versions without `~=`

```
tqdm
PyYAML
transformers
seqeval
viet-text-tools==0.1.1
```

Then we're left with the biggest question mark, `TorchCRF`, we actually have two libraries that shares similar API:

- `pip install pytorch-crf`: https://pytorch-crf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- `pip install TorchCRF`: https://pypi.org/project/TorchCRF/

Most probably you want the latter one, so given that the torch related dependencies are handled by `transformers`, you can try just underspecifying the version for this.

#### So you final requirements.txt would look like this:

```
tqdm
PyYAML
transformers
seqeval
viet-text-tools==0.1.1
TorchCRF
```

#### After trying the above, do a `pip freeze` to take note of all the actual version of the dependencies that are installed.

Then edit the versions in your `requirements.txt` file accordingly, you should see something like this:

```
tqdm
PyYAML
transformers==4.20.1
seqeval==1.2.2
viet-text-tools==0.1.1
TorchCRF==1.1.0
```

(Note: You might see a different set of versions on your machine depending on your setuptools/pip versions)

---

**Q: Do I always have to do these versioning manually?**

Most probably not if you're using `conda` and pycharm integration https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

**Q: Is it normal for environment setup to be so complicated?**

Not really, but if we are setting up an environment setup for code that we're not familiar with, it's a little trial and error, esp. when the `requirements.txt` has many flexible compatibility `~=`

Comment: Now that's will be the fun part =) Let me try to edit answer a little.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/torchcrf-dependencies, most probably you'll can fix those package versions as per the kaggle notebook example.

Comment: Try changing your Python version down to 3.9 or 3.10 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html =)